# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for... Jquery + Jplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jplayer

I'm using jPlayer and jQuery, getting the playlist item by AJAX. While declaring or adding new items to playlist (jPlayerPlaylist) i'm getting such an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for...

So what i'm doing:
Jquery:

```
 function my_track(){
       $.get("ajax.php?my_fav_track=1", function(data) 
       {
         myPlaylist.add(data);
       }
```

Response of Ajax:

```
{
"title":" Florence And The Machine  - <span class='artist_t'>Got The Love (Revolvr Remix)</span> <span class='dur'>5:40</span>",
"mp3":"http://xxx.xx/uploads/music/6/67/1376936969_florence-and-the-machine_-_.mp3"
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Any helps appreciated :)

Ok, userd $.getJSON:

```
$.getJSON('ajax.php?my_fav_track=1', function(data) {
          alert(data);
        });
```

Looked to Network, everything loaded but not alerting :(

Comment: data is probably a string, I'm guessing the player expects an object.

Comment: `$.getJSON()` maybe?!

Comment: sure, it's string. But when i convert string to JSON Object :
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
i'm getting : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Then it's not valid JSON

Comment: adeneo,
i validated using - http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com, but nothing

Comment: Guys, nothing works. Any ideas ?

Comment: `data` is already an object, not a string, you don't need to parse it. Show us the code of `myPlaylist.add`

Comment: myPlaylist.add - is the method of plugin jPlayer - http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/